# WAS gets hung WSVR0605W due to jdbc preparedstatement execute WCS

Tags: java, jdbc, was, wcs

I'm trying to execute three different prepared statements inside a function which basically does an insert in three different tables.

File registration.java

```
public  String regPoints(Timestamp time2, String usersID2) throws PDHException{
        String METHODNAME="regPoints";
        String msg = "Failure";
        Long lUserid,ldataid,lpointsid = 0L;Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps1=null,ps2=null,ps3 = null;
        try{lUserid = ECKeyManager.singleton().getNextKey("hp_loyalty_users"); 
        ldataid =  ECKeyManager.singleton().getNextKey("hp_loyalty_data"); 
        lpointsid = ECKeyManager.singleton().getNextKey("hp_loyalty_points"); 
        conn = createConnection();
        ps1=conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_REGISTRATION);
        ps2=conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_DATA_REGISTRATION);
        ps3=conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_POINTS_REGISTRATION);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        logMsg(Level.INFO, METHODNAME,"Registration Started for WCS userid: "+usersID2);
        logMsg(Level.INFO, METHODNAME,"Query started for users table to register");
        ps1.setLong(1, lUserid);
        ps1.setLong(2, Long.valueOf(usersID2));
        ps1.setInt(3, regPoints);
        ps1.setInt(4, Constants.LOYALTY_REG_DEFAULT);
        ps1.setTimestamp(5,time2);
        ps1.setTimestamp(6,time2);
        ps1.setString(7,Constants.LOYALTY_TRUE);
        ps1.addBatch();

        logMsg(Level.INFO, METHODNAME,"Query started for data table to register");
        ps2.setLong(1, ldataid);
        ps2.setLong(2, lUserid);
        ps2.setString(3, Constants.LOYALTY_NA);
        ps2.setString(4, Constants.LOYALTY_NA);
        ps2.setString(5, Constants.LOYALTY_NA);
        ps2.setFloat(6, Constants.LOYALTY_REG_DEFAULT);
        ps2.setInt(7, Constants.LOYALTY_REG_DEFAULT);
        ps2.setTimestamp(8,time2);
        ps2.setInt(9, regPoints);
        ps2.setInt(10, Constants.LOYALTY_REG_DEFAULT);
        ps2.setString(11, Constants.LOYALTY_REGISTRATION);
        ps2.setTimestamp(12,time2);
        ps2.setTimestamp(13,time2);
        ps2.setInt(14, Constants.LOYALTY_REG_DEFAULT);
        ps2.setString(15, Constants.LOYALTY_NA);
        ps2.addBatch();

        logMsg(Level.INFO, METHODNAME,"Query started for points table to register");
        ps3.setLong(1, lpointsid);
        ps3.setLong(2, lUserid);
        ps3.setInt(3, regPoints);
        ps3.setString(4, Constants.LOYALTY_FALSE);
        ps3.setLong(5, ldataid);
        ps3.setTimestamp(6,time2);
        ps3.setString(7, Constants.LOYALTY_FALSE);
        ps3.setTimestamp(8,time2);
        ps3.addBatch();

        int[] users = ps1.executeBatch();
        logMsg(Level.INFO, METHODNAME,"rows processed in users table: "+users.length);
        int[] data = ps2.executeBatch();
        logMsg(Level.INFO, METHODNAME,"rows processed in data table: "+data.length);
        int[] points = ps3.executeBatch();
        logMsg(Level.INFO, METHODNAME,"rows processed in data table: "+points.length);
        conn.commit();
        msg = "Success";
            logMsg(Level.INFO, METHODNAME,"Registration Completed for WCS userid: "+usersID2);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            if(null!=conn)
            {
                logMsg(Level.SEVERE, METHODNAME,"Registration Failed for WCS userid: "+usersID2);
                try {
                    conn.rollback();
                    throw new PDHException(e);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    throw new PDHException(e1);
                }
            }            
        }finally {
            JDBCUtils.closeStatement(ps1);
            JDBCUtils.closeStatement(ps2);
            JDBCUtils.closeStatement(ps3);
            JDBCUtils.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

createConnection method - I'm using ojdbc6.jar

```
private Connection createConnection() throws SQLException, Exception
     {
         final String METHODNAME = "createConnection";
        
         Connection dbConn = null;
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
         dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, CipherTextUtil.decodeHexString(userName) , CipherTextUtil.decodeHexString(pass));
         dbConn.setAutoCommit(false);
         return dbConn;
     }
```

When I call the regPoints function from a webpage in my local RAD or local environment its working perfectly fine. But the same doesn't work when it's running on a test environment. When I checked the logs I could see the below warning in the SystemOut.log and I had checked the database too. It never inserts any data because the initial insert is the point where it gets hung

```
[7/28/20 5:26:42:251 UTC] 00000096 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 2" (00000118) has been active for 324493 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:165)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:134)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:282)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:78)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1179)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeForRowsWithTimeout(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9870)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9974)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:213)
    at com.hp.commerce.hployalty.commands.HpLoyaltyTranscationCmdImpl.registrationFlow(HpLoyaltyTranscationCmdImpl.java:739)
    at com.hp.commerce.hployalty.commands.HpLoyaltyTranscationCmdImpl.performExecute(HpLoyaltyTranscationCmdImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.ECCommandTarget.executeCommand(ECCommandTarget.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.command.CommandCache.executeCommand(CommandCache.java:332)
    at com.ibm.websphere.command.CacheableCommandImpl.execute(CacheableCommandImpl.java:167)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.MeasuredCacheableCommandImpl.execute(MeasuredCacheableCommandImpl.java:68)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.AbstractECTargetableCommand.execute(AbstractECTargetableCommand.java:199)
    at com.hp.commerce.usermanagement.commands.ExtUserRegistrationAddCmdImpl.performExecute(ExtUserRegistrationAddCmdImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.ECCommandTarget.executeCommand(ECCommandTarget.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.command.CommandCache.executeCommand(CommandCache.java:332)
    at com.ibm.websphere.command.CacheableCommandImpl.execute(CacheableCommandImpl.java:167)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.MeasuredCacheableCommandImpl.execute(MeasuredCacheableCommandImpl.java:68)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.AbstractECTargetableCommand.execute(AbstractECTargetableCommand.java:199)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.BaseComponentImpl.executeCommand(BaseComponentImpl.java:285)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.WebAdapterComponentImpl.executeCommand(WebAdapterComponentImpl.java:46)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.objimpl.WebAdapterServiceBeanBase.executeCommand(WebAdapterServiceBeanBase.java:58)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.objects.EJSLocalStatelessWebAdapterService_ce749a4a.executeCommand(EJSLocalStatelessWebAdapterService_ce749a4a.java:31)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.objects.WebAdapterServiceAccessBean.executeCommand(WebAdapterServiceAccessBean.java:160)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.WebControllerHelper.executeCommand(WebControllerHelper.java:2781)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.BaseAction.invokeService(BaseAction.java:1600)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.LTPATokenGenerationEnabledBaseAction.invokeService(LTPATokenGenerationEnabledBaseAction.java:129)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.BaseAction.executeAction(BaseAction.java:663)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:152)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionServlet.processRequest(ECActionServlet.java:229)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionServlet.doPost(ECActionServlet.java:184)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionServlet.service(ECActionServlet.java:718)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.hp.ecom.b2c.service.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:132)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.services.servlet.filter.HttpSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpSecurityFilter.java:268)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.filter.CacheFilter$1.run(CacheFilter.java:390)
    at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:553)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.doFilterAction(RuntimeServletFilter.java:831)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.access$0(RuntimeServletFilter.java:614)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter$1.run(RuntimeServletFilter.java:458)
    at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.doFilter(RuntimeServletFilter.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.hp.filter.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:37)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.hp.seo.filter.SEOSecurityCheckFilter.doFilter(SEOSecurityCheckFilter.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.hp.seo.filter.SEOPdpCLPRedirectFilter.doFilter(SEOPdpCLPRedirectFilter.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.hp.seo.filter.SEOHPCoBrandDynamicToStaticFilter.doFilter(SEOHPCoBrandDynamicToStaticFilter.java:185)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.hp.seo.filter.SEOContentViewRedirectFilter.doFilter(SEOContentViewRedirectFilter.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.hp.seo.filter.SEOCaseConversionFilter.doFilter(SEOCaseConversionFilter.java:347)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.hp.vanity.filter.SEOVanityURLFilter.doFilter(SEOVanityURLFilter.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4047)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:768)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Is this something to do with jdbc version? Or do we have any specific reasons for this issue?

Comment: i tried with execute instead of executebatch too but no luck.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using, and which version of the Oracle JDBC driver (and ojdbc6 or similar is **not** the version of the driver).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  Thanks Mark. I had opened the manifest to find the version of jdbc driver and its "Specification-Version: 4.0" . Meanwhile Im using "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition  " Version - 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: Specification version 4 refers to the JDBC version (which is not surprising if you're using ojdbc6, which is for Java 6, and the JDBC version associated with Java 6 is JDBC 4.0). We need to know the version of the driver itself (which should be listed in the manifest as well AFAIK).

Comment: Ok this is what i see in manifest                                                                                                                 Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 1.5.0_17-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Implementation-Title: JDBC
Implementation-Version: 11.2.0.1.0
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: JDBC
Specification-Version: 4.0

Comment: Ok, so you have driver version 11.2.0.1.0, I'd recommend trying a newer version, eg a 12.1.x or newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to take the connection from connection pool instead of creating one to avoid the above issue. By default WCS doesnt allow executing batch statements using serverjdbchelperaccessbean. So i took the datasource from basejdbchelper class and got the connection.

```
DataSource ds = BaseJDBCHelper.getDataSource();
 Connection dbConn = ds.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time, when you want to know the JDBC version, just do "java -jar ojdbc8.jar". Also, as suggested, it is better to use the latest driver. If you have atleast JDK8 then you can use 19.7 even when your database is 12c. You can get JDBC drivers from [[Central Maven]](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html) or can download them from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html).

```
➜  lib **java -jar ojdbc8.jar**
Oracle 19.7.0.0.0 JDBC 4.2 compiled with javac 1.8.0_241 on Tue_Feb_11_04:20:00_PST_2020
#Default Connection Properties Resource
#Tue Jul 28 11:20:17 PDT 2020

***** JCE UNLIMITED STRENGTH IS INSTALLED ****
```

Comment: Thanks. Im just scared a bit to change this because it came with Websphere commerce which is currently being used  across other java applications inside my project. So changing this if in case affects other application it would be a problem